# Git merge strategy of upstream merge - how to apply `their` in case there is no our changes

Tags: git

Is there a way to apply `their` merge strategy for all conflicting files coming from upstream to our master in case none of our developers made any changes? Maybe it is worth asking how come we got conflicts on files we didnt change, but maybe it is off-topic in this context.

Comment: Git has no "theirs" merge *strategy*. There is an extended-option, `-X theirs`, that affects the *resolve* and *recursive* strategies. (Git's naming here is unfortunate.) If you are looking for `-X theirs`, it exists, but be careful with it: Git is not smart, it just follows very simple rules.

Comment: I'm aware of `-X theirs`, and it is not suitable, since there maybe real conflict with our changes, but sometimes (actually, in most cases) we get conflicts on files we didnt change, in this case I would like `their` being applied

Comment: OK: if you want to go file-by-file, consider using `git checkout-index --stage=all` on a conflicted file to get all three inputs, then using `git merge-file` on that one file. The merge-file command has the `--theirs` option as well. It's a bit tricky to use so you might want to wrap that all up in a script. This is effectively what `git mergetool` does, except that it is programmed to run someone's user-oriented merge tool rather than `git merge-file`.

Comment: It's probably more important, though, to figure out why you are seeing these merge conflicts in the first place. Use `git merge-base --all` to find the merge base commit, then `git diff --find-renames` that merge base commit vs the two branch tips, to see what Git is seeing.

Comment: If `git merge-base --all` finds *more than one* merge base, you have an unusual situation, and that could be the cause of some especially tricky issues.

Comment: I was thinking in the direction of wrapping in the script the following - `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U` get conflicting files list, then `git log --first-parent master --no-merges --committer="regex" --name-only --pretty=format:"" | sort -u` to match all files changed by our team (by mail, for example) and then just `git merge-file --theirs` on each file from the first list in case it is not in the second list. WDYT?

Comment: You can do that, but I'd still look at what Git is seeing. Remember, Git doesn't merge commit-by-commit: it merges by comparing single a common starting point with two branch tips. If you're seeing conflicts in files you didn't change, then ... well, even if you you did not change them yourself, you acquired changes *to* them, and you may well be depending on those.

Comment: I think the difference is because we are working with "stable" tags, changes for these tags are not merged back to master but each "stable" starts from master, so I guess when rebasing from one "stable" to another git sees a lot of "changes" because the common ancestor is somewhere waaay behind. In any case, it is not something we can change, so we have to do something with consequences.

Comment: That would make sense: you're getting conflicts here because *they* made changes. But here you mention *rebase* rather than *merge*. If you are truly running rebase (not merge) here, your problem is likely that you're selecting *their* commits to copy in your rebase, along with your own commits.

Comment: So the merge would be more appropriate than rebase?

Comment: Almost certainly. You do have to make your own decisions here, and if you do want to use rebase instead of merge, you really will want to pick out *your* commits rather than theirs. But usually with something like this, merge is easier and better over time.